# App incompatibility

Tags: java, codenameone

Upon Launching one of my projects , the setup is giving me an incompatibility error respons under codenameone.

This error is given on windows desktop application only.

Below is the error response that I am getting
[image]

Comment: based on the same error someone got here http://steamcommunity.com/app/295110/discussions/0/616199347851366553/ is it possible that you have a 32bit windows and whatever you try to run requires the 64bit version?

Comment: Is this a result of the Windows Desktop build, running the simulator, designer? It's unclear what you did to produce this error?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you run a plugin, which not compatible with your actual version of windows?